# How to delete the whole line in the list if item='Pending' Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a http request:

```
tempEvses.addAll(newItems.map<Evse>((items) {
          final evseID = items['evseID'];
          final friendlyName = items['friendlyName'];
          final registrationStatus = items['registrationStatus'];
          final street = items['street'];
          final streetNumber = items['streetNumber'];
          final region = items['region'];
          final lat = items['latitude'] ?? 0.0;
          final lng = items['longitude'] ?? 0.0;
          final connectorList = items['connectorWSList'];
          final cpSerial = items['cpSerial'];
          final img = items['img'];

          return new Evse(evseID: evseID, friendlyName: friendlyName,registrationStatus:registrationStatus, street: street, streetNumber: streetNumber, region: region, lat: lat, lng: lng, connectorList: connectorList, cpSerial: cpSerial, img: img);


        }).toList());
```

if `registrationStatus='Pending'` then no one of items should enter the list. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `for loop` you can achieve this:

```
    List result = [];
    for (var items in newItems) {
      final evseID = items['evseID'];
      final friendlyName = items['friendlyName'];
      final registrationStatus = items['registrationStatus'];
      final street = items['street'];
      final streetNumber = items['streetNumber'];
      final region = items['region'];
      final lat = items['latitude'] ?? 0.0;
      final lng = items['longitude'] ?? 0.0;
      final connectorList = items['connectorWSList'];
      final cpSerial = items['cpSerial'];
      final img = items['img'];
      if (registrationStatus == 'Pending') {
        result.add(new Evse(
            evseID: evseID,
            friendlyName: friendlyName,
            registrationStatus: registrationStatus,
            street: street,
            streetNumber: streetNumber,
            region: region,
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng,
            connectorList: connectorList,
            cpSerial: cpSerial,
            img: img));
      }
    }

    tempEvses.addAll(result);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `.where()` on the list?

Comment: Also I think it might be `if (registrationStatus == 'Pending') {`